# python cursor.callproc() function not calling procedure

Tags: python, stored-procedures, debian, mariadb

New(ish)  to SQL, just discovered stored procedures.

Restructuring a monolithic Python 3.7 script.

Here's my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE domSel(IN xip VARCHAR(16))
BEGIN
SELECT domain FROM pytest.nodes2 WHERE ip = xip
END;
```

It selects a domain based off an IP. The original code snippet in Python looks like this:

```
    for i,x,y in ip_ll:
        cursorA.execute("SELECT domain FROM pytest.nodes2 WHERE ip = '" + str(i) + "'")
        hosts_low.append(cursorA.fetchone())
        ips_low_latency.append(i)
        lat_low.append(x)
```

The following line is supposed to be the replacement:

```
# The #s are of course the IP address.
result_arg = cursorA.callproc('domSel', args=('###.##.###.###,))
print(result_arg[1])
```

But it's giving me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./2queryMagic.py", line 45, in <module>
    print(result_arg[1])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I tried to print arg[0], but of course that's the argument name. I tried iterating over the results in a for loop, this didn't work either... Python doesn't seem to be calling the procedure. Hopefully this is enough information, banging my head off the desk atm.

Comment: Your stored procedure doesn't seem to have any OUT variable: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-callproc.html

Comment: Been using these docs as gospel this week, and didn't process the fact that an OUT variable is required lol. I've redefined my function, and it's still not behaving as I'd like...

Comment: MariaDB [pytest]> call domSel('194.36.110.199', domain);
ERROR 1414 (42000): OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine pytest.domSel is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger
MariaDB [pytest]> call domSel('194.36.110.199');
ERROR 1318 (42000): Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE pytest.domSel; expected 2, got 1
MariaDB [pytest]>

Comment: The output variable I used was dom VARCHAR(30)

Comment: I tried MariaDB [pytest]> call domSel('194.36.110.199', dom);
ERROR 1414 (42000): OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine pytest.domSel is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

Comment: Sorry!! My bad, I used @ before the out variable and... SUCCESS!! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

As per rdas' comment, precedures require an out variable, and they must be referenced with @var_name

```
call domSel('###.##.###.###', @dom);

(worked, but ofc relayed the actual domain)
+-------------------+
| domain            |
+-------------------+
| -domain.com      -|
+-------------------+
```